# Data visualisation (BI) tools for non web Software development with Java

Tags: java, swing, javafx, tableau-api, qlikview

I am developing non web Software in Java. I am using MS SQL for database. I want more results in Visualistion form. But Java has limited data visualisation ability. So can I use visualisation tool (like Qlik, tableau...) with java and Ms SQL. My concepts are not clear. My partial java program gives result with SWING and I wuld like to further develop software with more visualistion effects. How shouldI develop the software? Please help me.
Thank you.

[image: 3D Bar chart]

Comment: There's [jfreechart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) available under LGPL license

Comment: @  Lance Java : Jfreechart can not give3d  bar chart. Please check attached 3D Bar chart picture.

Comment: There's also [orsoncharts](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/)

Comment: I would suggest whatever tool you use, do not, under **any** circumstances, try to replicate what you have in the picture.

Comment: @  Skip Intro : ohh..is there any solution? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you want it to work. If you want scheduled reloads of data that's stored somewhere within or related to your Java app, then the main question would be how Qlik can access that - is there an API, an ODBC connection, a SQL server, file output? If so, then Qlik could periodically load from that and you could embed this back in your Java app if you wanted.

If you want the display to be fully dynamic (i.e. the user can enter data in your Java app and it shows in a Qlik visualisation immediately) then you'd need to be using the APIs to create Qlik objects on the fly. There are lots of APIs for Qlik Sense that are [documented here](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/3.1/Content/APIs-and-SDKs.htm). I don't have extensive experience of them, but you'd probably need to start looking at the Engine API if you want on-the-fly apps and visualisations.